# TypeError: draw() missing 1 required positional argument: 'win'

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
class rocket(object):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.image = pygame.image.load('sprites/spaceship.png')
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 72
    self.height = 72
    self.speed = 5
    self.angle = 0

def draw(self, win):
    win.blit(char, (self.x,self.y))

def updateGameWindow():
win.blit(bg, (0,0))
rocket.draw(win)
pygame.display.update()
```

For some reason when I run this program,  I'm getting the error that `rocket.draw(win)` is missing the argument 'win' when it is clearly there.

`win` is defined at the top of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`draw()` needs to be called on a `rocket` instance, not the class itself:

```
rocket_instance = rocket(some_x, some_y)
rocket_instance.draw(win)
```

In the first line of the code above, you are creating an instance of the rocket class, and on the second line you are calling the `draw()` method on that instance where the instance itself is passed implicitly as the `self` argument.

In your example code, you are getting an error from this line `rocket.draw(win)` because, since you are calling `draw()` on the class itself instead of an instance, the instance is not passed as the `self` argument, and instead the `win` argument is passed for the `self` param, and everything blows up because now there is no expected `win` argument passed.

Comment: I've been trying to solve this for about an hour haha I cant believe i forgot to make an instance... Thank you!